# Best way to authenticate for Funding balance with API call

Tags: authentication, web-application, mobile, payment-gateway

I have an API call where a user adds to their balance when funds are low. The actual payment is done via Braintree, but I need to allow the user to make that call via their API.

What would be a good way to do this? Two-factor authentication wouldn't really work for my use case, as I want the user to be able to automatically add funds when their balance is low. Here is what I am thinking so far:

```
requests.POST(https_url, data={
                    API_KEY: '1234',
                    API_SECRET_KEY: '1234',
                    LAST_FOUR_CC: '9999',
                    AMOUNT_IN_USD: '10.00'
             })
```

Would the above be ok? If not, what would be a better way of providing a verification (such as the last four of CC#)? I am thinking either use the CVC or last four of credit card. If this isn't ok, what would be a better idea?

Comment: I'm not sure that this question is answerable. Are you asking about the architecture? Payment processing best practice? You've not given us anything to really provide an answer, and I suspect that if you do, then you really need more specialized programming answers and not an Info Sec perspective.